# Can I hide certain upload folders in media library

Tags: functions, uploads, media

A Plugin ( download monitor ) saves uploaded files in a certain folder called "dlm_uploads" within the WP upload directory. All files are visible in Media Library. Unfortunately the upload path cannot be changed in the plugin. can I hide this folder in the media library? thanks

Comment: oh, that's quite similar. but i don't know how to change meta_query from "key" to post-type "dlm_downloads" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit quick and dirty, but this should work:

```
function media_library_hide_dlm_downloads($where) {
   if(isset($_POST['action']) && ( $_POST['action'] == 'query-attachments')) {
      $where .= ' AND guid NOT LIKE "%wp-content/uploads/dlm_downloads%"';
   }

   return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'media_library_hide_dlm_downloads');
```

Read more about the [posts_where filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/).

Comment: Yes! Works great for Grid View ... I am honest. Have no idea but I am full of hope! Just to mention, I disabled LIST view with "display:none". Thanks :)